# Derivin the Moment Generating Function

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Question:

Suppose f(x) = 1/10 for 0 < x < 10 and f(x) = 0 elsewhere, compute mx(s) for all s in the Reals

This is what I have so far:

mx(s) = E(e^(sX))

= integral (from 0 to 10) of (e^(sX))(1/10)dx)

= (1/10)integral (from 0 to 10) of (e^(sX))dx)

I don't know how to integrate further, I think you have to do substitution? I also don't really know if i'm on the right track

Answer (score 1):

We want to calculate $E(e^{sX})$. This is
$$\int_0^{10} \frac{e^{sx}}{10}\,dx.$$
Integrate. Note that in the integration $s$ is treated as a constant. You can if you wish make the substitution $w=sx$. Or else you can write down a antiderivative directly: you have integrated, for example, $e^{2x}$ enough times to remember what happens.

So, for  $s\ne 0$, we get 
$$\left.\frac{1}{10s}e^{sx}\right|_0^{10}.$$
In the case $s=0$, we are just integrating $\frac{1}{10}e^{(0)(x)}$, and get $1$.
(We did the case $s=0$ for completeness.)

**Remark:** Note that $X$ is a random variable. For any fixed value of $s$, $E(e^{sX})$ is also a random variable.

The *integration*, as usual, uses a dummy variable of integration we chose to call $x$. Part of your difficulty may be that you wrote $\int_0^{10}e^{sX}\,dx$, mixing up the random variable $X$ and the dummy variable of integration.